# Preparing Test class for parameterized beforeDelete()?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I'm trying to create test class for beforeDelete().But I'm confusing on passing parameters.Kindly help me.

### Apex Class :

```java
public class TriggerService {
    
    public static void beforeDelete(List<Call__c> triggerOld, Map<Id, Call__c> triggerOldMap){
        //ByPass for integration user profile
        if(ZTS_US_UserProfileCheck.isIntegrationUser(UserInfo.getUserId())) return;
        
        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;

        USCallService.delSampleDrop(triggerOld);
        if(profileName !='System Administrator'){
            USCallService.delSubmittedCall(triggerOld);
        }
        if(!USGlobalVariablesService.isEventDeletingCall){
            USGlobalVariablesService.isCallDeletingEvent = true;
            USCallService.deleteRelatedEvents(triggerOldMap);
        }
    }   
    
}
```

```java
@isTest
public class TriggerServiceTest {

    @isTest 
    static void beforeDeleteTest(){
    
        //Create an Account
        
        Account acc = new Account();         
        acc.name = 'Test Account';
        acc.ZTS_EU_Country__c = 'United States';
        acc.BillingCity = 'Test City';
        acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c = '12345';
        //acc.ZTS_EU_State_County__c  = 'Ohio';
        acc.BillingStreet = 'Test Street'; 
        acc.BillingPostalCode = '12344';
        acc.BillingState = 'Test State'; 
        acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c = '';
        insert acc;
                                
        //Create one Call
    
        Call__c call = new Call__c();
        call.ZTS_EU_Account__c = acc.Id;
        call.Name = 'Test Call';                

        DateTime startdatetime = DateTime.newInstance(2021, 03, 17, 12, 0, 0);
        DateTime enddatetime = DateTime.newInstance(2021, 03, 17, 12, 30, 0);
        call.ZTS_EU_Sub_Type__c = 'Account Call';
        call.ZTS_EU_Start_Date_Time__c = startdatetime;
        call.ZTS_EU_End_Date_Time__c = enddatetime;
        call.ZTS_EU_Status__c = 'Submitted';
        call.ZTS_EU_Duration__c = '0.5 Hour';
        call.ZTS_EU_Call_Owner__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        insert call;    
        
        // How to pass parameters here please help me on this I have stucked at this point.
        
        TriggerService.beforeDelete();
    }
}
```

How to create test data and how to pass parameters in this methods.Please anyone help on this I have stucked at this point.

Thanks In advance,
Chandu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a trigger handler so you're abstracting away part of the logic which is a great practice.

Due to that abstraction, `TriggerService.beforeDelete` doesn't care what context it's running in, it just knows to accept a `List<Call__c>` and a `Map<Id, Call__c>`. You can pass in any parameters you want that meet that requirement - they don't have to be `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.oldMap` context variables. Take your `call` object and put it into a List and a Map and pass them to your service.

```java
Map<Id, Call__c> mockOldMap = new Map<Id, Call__c>{
    call.Id => call
};
TriggerService.beforeDelete(mockOldMap.values(), mockOldMap);
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I feel like it's missing something imporant. Of course abstraction can be a good thing, but you will also want a unit test that covers (and asserts the functionality of) the full delete trigger. So OP should also add a test through which the function gets called because of an actual delete, by simply deleting a record in a unit test.

Comment: There are a few areas that can be improved. There's value in testing the logic in a trigger handler is working and also in testing the trigger itself. From the code provided it's not clear what benefits are being gained by using `TriggerService` vs. having the logic directly in a trigger as it appears the deleted records are passed to some static services that are prime for dependency injection depending on what they do. The unit test _also_ hits the database before calling a handler directly. Again, that's not clear from the code provided so I tried to answer as directly as possible.

Comment: You're right, you did answer the question directly and correctly, which I like (here, have an upvote :-) My comment was not meant as criticism in that regard, more of an elaboration.